# Use COALESCE in prepareStatement for "insert into" cmd

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, hsqldb

I am trying to execute below cmd but this one is throwing an exception:

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in operation

```
conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TableA (colA) VALUES (IFNULL(?, 1)))
```

Here TableA has colA with integer datatype.
However, if I change above cmd to

```
conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TableA (colA) VALUES(IFNULL(null, 1)))
```

works properly but doesn't make any sense because want to pass colA value at runtime.

code:

```
   ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TableA (colA) VALUES(IFNULL(?, 1))")

   ps.setObject(1, 5);  // this cmd doesn't have any problem code is failing at preparestatement itself
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add your Java code.

Comment: I think this is a problem with passing the parameter, not the code.  How is the parameter set?  Clarify in your question.

Comment: has only 2 lines of code

Comment: This should work with the latest version of HSQLDB. Which version are you using?

Comment: And what is the CREATE TABLE statement?

Answer (score 1):

setObject is generic so if you want to force to use a type you can use the third parameter as follow:

```
ps.setObject(1, 5, JDBCType.INTEGER);
```

Because you have used a constant value, so your compiler must decide if is an integer or another numeric type.

You can write also

```
Integer myValue = 5;
ps.setObject(1, myValue);
```

or

```
Integer myValue = 5;
ps.setObject(1, myValue.intValue());
```

Comment: @BhawaniSingh please post the error you have with my code

Comment: getting `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in operation` while executing `conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO TableA (colA) VALUES (IFNULL(?, 1))")`  line

Comment: @BhawaniSingh are you sure colA has integer as datatype?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInt` instead of `setObject`

```
ps.setInt(1, 5);
```

Comment: it's failing in prepareStatement itself